# Splash screen blocks interaction

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, splash-screen

My app uses the standard splash screen that comes with ionic. I haven't changed anything in the xml or the splashscreens themself. When I open the app on my iPhone, the splash screen shows up and then starts fading out, but when I tap the screen too soon (when the fading isn't done yet), nothing responds to my clicks anymore, even when it's done fading out. If I wait until the splash screen is fully faded out (so not touching the splash screen), then everything responds to my clicks. Also, tapping the splash screen right after opening the app doesn't cause this problem, it's only when tapping during the end phase of the fade.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: look for errors in the console. maybe your code is responsible...

Comment: I checked the console and can't find anything special. It loads some plugins and then says 'Resetting plugins due to page load', after that it says Finished load of: ...index.html. I removed the splashscreen as a test, but didn't work. I can't get rid of the splashscreen completely btw, it shows the standard Cordova splashscreen for 1 second or so. When it disappears and I try to click on the textfield right away, the problem occurs.. If I wait at least 2 secs or so, I can hit the text field.

Comment: Also, when this problem occurs and it 'gets stuck', and then hit the home button and try to open it again, it only shows the Cordova start screen (grey with the cordova icon in center). It doesn't even proceed to load.. I have to quit the app using the multitask manager thing.